# $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is normal $\iff \forall P\in M_n(\mathbb C) : \ P^{*}AP$ is normal where $P$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the following statement correct?

> $A\in M_n(\mathbb C)$ is normal $\iff \forall P\in M_n(\mathbb C)  : \ P^{*}AP$ is normal where $P$ is normal.

I tried to prove it and I failed, here is what I have so far:

$$P^*AP \ \ \  \mbox{is normal}\implies \\ (P^*AP)(P^*AP)^*=(P^*AP)^*(P^*AP) \implies \\ (P^*AP)(P^*A^*P)=(P^*A^*P)(P^*AP)$$

And there is nothing else I can derive from here...

I also tried to disprove it but I'm not sure how to find a unitary similar matrix to $A$. Thus, from the examples I could generate I was able to show that if $A$ is normal $P^{-1}AP$ isn't normal.

For example :

$$A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\0 & 3\end{array}\right), \quad B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 5\\0 & 3\end{array}\right)$$

$A$ is normal and similar to $B$ but $B$ isn't normal.

I'm quite confused. I believe the statement is false (because I couldn't prove it) but yet I don't know how to find a counter-example to show it.

Comment: Isn't $P$ assumed to be unitary?

Comment: I don't understand: haven't you just shown a counterexample to the claim? What are you confused about then?

Comment: Because the $B$ I found satisfies $P^{-1}AP=B$ for some $P$ but not satisfies $P^{*}AP=B$ . I should find a $B$ such that $P^*AP=B$.

Comment: Use quantifiers please, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: If you mean $$\forall A(A\text{ is normal}\iff \exists P(P\text{ is unitary }\land P^*AP\text{ is normal})),$$ the statement is true.

Comment: @GitGud are you sure you used the quantifiers you want now?

Comment: I've edited my question. I was looking for a $P$ which is normal.

Comment: @quid Yes. Do you suspect I overlooked something?

Comment: It's still not clear. Do you want $P^*AP$ to be normal for *all* (not true) or for *some* (true) normal $P$?

Comment: I want $P^*AP$ to be normal for all $P$.

Comment: @GitGud it would  seem more natural with for all $P$.

Comment: @quiz Yes, but still, it would be better if the question was posed in a way which avoids any "natural substitutions" :)

Comment: Great:) Thank you very much. Sorry for misleading you (It was kinda obvious to me when I wrote it but I can see why it isn't obvious in general).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel no doubt about that, which is why I did not object to the remark but merely requested clarification on the proposed formulation that seemed somewhat contrived to me.  Though the main issue in my mind are not the quantifiers but rather that the type of $P$ was not specified. It now is.  Personally I am still pretty sure that $P$  is rather intended as unitary. But, well, we are no mindreaders. Or it might just be a for my taste somewhat strange exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, e.g., matrices
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}\quad\text{and}\quad P=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}.
$$
Both are normal ($A$ is a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix, $P$ is Hermitian), but
$$
P^*AP=\pmatrix{5&1\\7&5}
$$
is not normal since
$$
[P^*AP,P^*A^*P]=48\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}.
$$